# Streamlit install fails on GitLab CI with UnicodeEncodeError

Tags: unicode, pip, gitlab, streamlit

On GitLab CI, after upgrading `streamlit` to 1.10.0, I have the following error while running `pip install streamlit`:

```
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/builds/project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 164, in exc_logging_wrapper
    status = run_func(*args)
  File "/builds/project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 205, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
  File "/builds/project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 413, in run
    pycompile=options.compile,
  File "/builds/lproject/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/__init__.py", line 81, in install_given_reqs
    pycompile=pycompile,
  File "/builds/project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_install.py", line 810, in install
    requested=self.user_supplied,
  File "/builds/project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/install/wheel.py", line 737, in install_wheel
    requested=requested,
  File "/builds/project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/install/wheel.py", line 589, in _install_wheel
    file.save()
  File "/builds/project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/install/wheel.py", line 383, in save
    if os.path.exists(self.dest_path):
  File "/builds/project/venv/lib/python3.6/genericpath.py", line 19, in exists
    os.stat(path)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\U0001f4f9' in position 76: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I checked the faulty encoded character and it corresponds to the video camera emoji  [= `\U0001f4f9`](https://codepoints.net/U+1F4F9).

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug has been introduced by Streamlit 1.10.0. The video camera emoji has been added to the `streamlit hello` command after the introduction of the multi-page feature: https://github.com/streamlit/streamlit/tree/release/1.10.0/lib/streamlit/hello/pages

In my CI, the encodings were the following:

```bash
$ locale || true
LANG=
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="POSIX"
LC_NUMERIC="POSIX"
LC_TIME="POSIX"
LC_COLLATE="POSIX"
LC_MONETARY="POSIX"
LC_MESSAGES="POSIX"
LC_PAPER="POSIX"
LC_NAME="POSIX"
LC_ADDRESS="POSIX"
LC_TELEPHONE="POSIX"
LC_MEASUREMENT="POSIX"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="POSIX"
LC_ALL=
```

I reset them using:

```yaml
before_script:
    - apt-get install -y locales
    - echo "en_US UTF-8" > /etc/locale.gen
    - locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
    - export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
    - export LANGUAGE=en_US:en
    - export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

and now it works.

Thanks to [Bill's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72379600/5446749).