# Error when pip installing simpletransformers

Tags: python, pip, pre-trained-model, simpletransformers

I am trying to install simpletransformers via pip, but it gives me the following error:

```
"ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/sw/arch/Debian10/EB_production/2021/software/Python/3.9.5-GCCcore-10.3.0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 180, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/sw/arch/Debian10/EB_production/2021/software/Python/3.9.5-GCCcore-10.3.0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 204, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
  File "/sw/arch/Debian10/EB_production/2021/software/Python/3.9.5-GCCcore-10.3.0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 393, in run
    installed = install_given_reqs(
  File "/sw/arch/Debian10/EB_production/2021/software/Python/3.9.5-GCCcore-10.3.0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/__init__.py", line 77, in install_given_reqs
    requirement.install(
  File "/sw/arch/Debian10/EB_production/2021/software/Python/3.9.5-GCCcore-10.3.0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_install.py", line 782, in install
    install_wheel(
  File "/sw/arch/Debian10/EB_production/2021/software/Python/3.9.5-GCCcore-10.3.0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/install/wheel.py", line 810, in install_wheel
    _install_wheel(
  File "/sw/arch/Debian10/EB_production/2021/software/Python/3.9.5-GCCcore-10.3.0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/install/wheel.py", line 653, in _install_wheel
    file.save()
  File "/sw/arch/Debian10/EB_production/2021/software/Python/3.9.5-GCCcore-10.3.0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/install/wheel.py", line 419, in save
    with open(self.dest_path, "wb") as dest:
UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\U0001f4f9' in position 75: ordinal not in range(256)
```

"

I am working on jupyterhub and have tried creating a conda environment with Python version 3.7 as suggested in other cases, but the problem was not solved.

Any tips are welcome!

Comment: Does this happen only with `simpletransformers` package or any package? Also, please provide a stacktrace of the error.

Comment: It only happens with simpletransformers, I edited the file to add the entire error. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from the encodage.
I think these topics could help you.

[Streamlit install fails on GitLab CI with UnicodeEncodeError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72606058/streamlit-install-fails-on-gitlab-ci-with-unicodeencodeerror)

['ascii' codec can't encode character : ordinal not in range (128)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56104377/ascii-codec-cant-encode-character-ordinal-not-in-range-128/72379600#72379600)

In general google your error message you'll find o lot of related post and maybe your answer.