# UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 55-56: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, huggingface-transformers

I'm trying huggingface models on aws lambda but its throwing an error

Here's my code.

```
import json
from transformers import pipeline

nlp = pipeline("zero-shot-classification")

def handler(event, context):
    print(event['text'])
    sequence = "Who are you voting for in 2020?"
    candidate_labels = ["politics", "public health", "economics"]
    print(sequence)
    print(candidate_labels)

    response = {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "body": nlp(sequence, candidate_labels)[0]
    }
    return response
```

I get the following error

> File "/function/awslambdaric/bootstrap.py", line 283, in write
> self.stream.write(msg) UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode
> characters in position 55-56: ordinal not in range(128)

What is wrong?

Comment: Search online for the error message to find out. Your code is not useful without knowing the data it operates on, btw. As a new user here, also read [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt that's very unhelpful. The data is there in the code If you care to read it. The only reason I posted a question here is I couldn't find answer then.  SO has always been this hostile. That's why I created a new account. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

adding `PYTHONIOENCODING=utf8` as an environment variable and changing the line

`"body": nlp(sequence, candidate_labels)[0]`

to

`"body": nlp(sequence, candidate_labels)`

worked.

Comment: this post was useful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56104377/ascii-codec-cant-encode-character-ordinal-not-in-range-128